# ElasticSearch API - update by query script params null_pointer_exception

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-api

I am new to the ElasticSearch and am i trying to make use of the _update_by_query route. I am sending this body:

```
{
"query": {
    "match": {
        "id": "fdfsfsfs-058f-437d-bc52-473808ba61c2"
    }
},
"script": {
    "inline": "ctx._source.addresses.add(params.data)",
    "params": {
        "data": {
            "street": "Road",
            "number": 15,
            "county": "WWW"
        }
    }
}
```

}

but I get the following response:

```
{
"error": {
    "root_cause": [
        {
            "type": "script_exception",
            "reason": "runtime error",
            "script_stack": [
                "ctx._source.addresses.add(params.data)",
                "                                ^---- HERE"
            ],
            "script": "ctx._source.addresses.add(params.data)",
            "lang": "painless",
            "position": {
                "offset": 30,
                "start": 0,
                "end": 36
            }
        }
    ],
    "type": "script_exception",
    "reason": "runtime error",
    "script_stack": [
        "ctx._source.addresses.add(params.data)",
        "                              ^---- HERE"
    ],
    "script": "ctx._source.addresses.add(params.data)",
    "lang": "painless",
    "position": {
        "offset": 30,
        "start": 0,
        "end": 36
    },
    "caused_by": {
        "type": "null_pointer_exception",
        "reason": null
    }
},
"status": 400
```

}

I don't know what could be the error, since I do pass my params and they are inside the "script" object. Does anyone have an idea of what could be wrong?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Are you sure that your document `fdfsfsfs-058f-437d-bc52-473808ba61c2` has a field called `addresses` which is not null?

Comment: Hi @Val, yes, i am, I checked that.

Comment: How many documents match your query? I bet there are more than one because you're using `match` instead of `term`?

Comment: You are right @Val! Thank you very much! Switching to "term" solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the `match` query actually matches several documents and one of them doesn't have any field called `addresses`.

You probably need to change to a `term` query in order to do an exact match and only select the single document that you would like to update.